# ListView section data (react-native)

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I'd like to create a two-tier  (section >> entry) listview in react-native  similar to ListViewPagingExample from UIExplorerApp but using blob data / json to populate sections info. Also, I'm confused as to what parameter values to pass on to cloneWithRowsAndSections.

Can't find anything regarding the above topic from docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content) but only the mention that it is possible. Some examples would be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code for ListViewDataSource [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/72d3d724a3a0c6bc46981efd0dad8f7f61121a47/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListViewDataSource.js#L163).

The cloneWithRows method is defined as:

```
cloneWithRows(
    dataBlob: Array<any> | {[key: string]: any},
    rowIdentities: ?Array<string>
)
```

Whereas cloneWithRowsAndSections is:

cloneWithRowsAndSections(
    dataBlob: any,
    sectionIdentities: ?Array,
    rowIdentities: ?Array>
)

The `sectionIdentities` parameter is documented as:

> This is an array of identifiers for sections. ie. ['s1', 's2', ...]. 
>   If not provided, it's assumed that the keys of dataBlob are the
>   section identities.